# Is it possible to create MIME message object without using javamail API?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, mime, mail-server

I intend not to use javamail API. I'm planning to send the message via SSLSocket. I have established a secure SSL/TLS connection. But how do I create a MIME object without importing javax.mail.*; package inorder to send via the socket

```
 protected static MimeMessage attach() throws IOException, MessagingException {

        Properties properties = System.getProperties();

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(from, password);
            }
        });

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject(messageSubject);

        BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart1.setText(messageBody);

        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();

        String filename = attPath;
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart2.setFileName(filename);



        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart3 = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart3.setText("\nBye");



        //ATTACH 3 BODY PARTS
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart3);


        message.setContent(multipart);


        return message;

    }
```

Comment: String concatenation.  Is there some reason you don't want to use the JavaMail API?

Comment: @BillShannon Yes, I do not want to use JavaMail API. I intend to learn the email process at the socket level in SSL/TLS connection, without the default methods from the JavaMail API.

Comment: Have fun with that!

Comment: @BillShannon And I'm quite successful @ sending emails via SSL sockets.........:)  It is the MIME part that I am worried about

Comment: The general case of MIME is complex.  If you only need to handle a few specific cases, it's easier.  But please, please, please read and understand the RFCs.  Learn how to read a BNF syntax specification.  Don't try to guess at what is required by looking at examples.